# Does DKIM require to send email via one specific server?

Tags: email-server, exim, dkim

I'm just starting with DKIM. I enabled it to our DirectAdmin server.

Now its enabled, does it require that **each mail is send via our server** to be signed correctly? So, our customer needs *always* set his outgoing mail server to ours?

What happens when you send mail via your xDSL providers smtp server?

Comment: That's kind of the point. What was your goal in enabling DKIM, and what did you expect?

Comment: @The requirement to DKIM sign or originate messages from the hosts specified in you SPF record can be advertised with a DMARC record.  Gmail, Yahoo and other will use this in their spam determination.

Comment: @Law29 its on request of a customer. I just wasn't sure if they *must* send all emails via our server. Often they choose the SMTP of their ISP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) require that each mail is send **via *our* server** to be signed correctly?

In short, no.

DKIM signatures include a *selector* to indicate which key was used to sign the message.  If your customers use an alternate mail server that wants to add DKIM signatures to the mail messages from your customers you can add the public key  for that mail server to your DNS (**`selector_for_other_server`**`._domainkey.example.com IN TXT`) and thereby confirm that that server is also an authenticated sender.

If that alternate server does not add DKIM signatures, you have the same situation as you had before you enabled DKIM on your mail server.

Comment: If the alternate server does not add DKIM signatures, then surely the problem is worse than before DKIM was enabled, because recipients will see that the mail was is supposed to be DKIM-signed and isn't?

Comment: They receive an unsigned message, yes, but how are they supposed to know that it could have been signed? DKIM provides proof that a signed message is authentic, but the lack of a signature does not prove that a message is spoofed.

Comment: OK . . . I think I didn't really realize you *could* advertise DKIM without also specifying through SPF/DMARC that messages *must* be signed :)